# Unit test asp.net route mapping extension method

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-5, routes

I have an extension class for Routes. I want to test the updated list of routecollection. This is an extract:

```
public static void MapMyRoutes(this RouteCollection routes)
{
    //do some stuff
    routes.MapHttpRoute(null, controllerPath.Path, new { @namespace = controllerPath.Namespace, controller = controllerPath.ControllerName, id = UrlParameter.Optional });
}
```

I want to unit test this extension, but can't work out how to extract the mapped url from the routecollection:

This is a test:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMapMyRoutesMapsCorrectly()
{
    var routes = new RouteCollection();
    routes.MapMyRoutes();

    foreach (var route in routes)
    {
        Assert.AreEqual(route.??, "v1/api/myRoute");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[RoutesCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.routecollection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is defined as a `Collection<RouteBase>` so cast each item as a Route, ie:

```
foreach (var route in routes.Cast<Route>())
{
    // Url may not in fact be the correct property …
    Assert.AreEqual(route.Url, "v1/api/myRoute");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To be honest you are putting wrong logic to test void method. As your method is void you should use mock framework and pass the mocked `RouteCollection` object in `MapMyRoutes(this RouteCollection routes)` method and then verify `routes.MapHttpRoute` method call.

Refer [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13820809/unit-test-a-method-that-returns-a-void) for code implementation

Comment: I want to test the urls though, not just verify that the method is called