# How to unit test DAO Update/Remove methods that return void?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, testing, asp.net-core-webapi

I have two methods, which I'm really not sure how to test. They are in the `UserService` class:

```
    public async Task UpdateUser(int userId, UserInput userInput)
    {
        var user = await _userRepository.Get(userId);
        if (user != null)
        {
            user.Name = userInput.Name;
            _userRepository.Update(user);
        }
    }

    public async Task RemoveUser(int userId)
    {
        var user = await _userRepository.Get(userId);
        if (user != null)
        {
            _userRepository.Remove(user);
        }
    }
```

And here is the test I wrote for `Update` method:

```
    [Fact]
    public async void UpdateUser()
    {
        var repository = new Mock<IUserRepository>();
        repository.Setup(r => r.Get(1)).ReturnsAsync(new User(1, "John Doe"));
        repository.Setup(r => r.Update(It.IsAny<User>()));

        var userService = new UserService(repository.Object, SingletonAutoMapper.Mapper);

        var userInput = new UserInput { Name = "John Doe" };
        await userService.Update(1, userInput);
    }
```

So in `UpdateUser`, the only methods I'm using are from repository, that I'm telling exactly what to return. Moreover I don't even return anything from it (`PUT` web api method should return `204 No Content` status).

(`Mapper` is used in this class, but not in these two methods, so please don't mind)

Can I leave this test without `Assert` method? If not, How should I test it?

Comment: Have the mock verify that it received the expected input

Comment: @Nkosi I'm not sure if I understand your question. The test I posted that's all I got.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unit Test a method that returns a void](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13820809/unit-test-a-method-that-returns-a-void)

Comment: @devNull Yes, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have the mock verify that it received the expected input

```
[Fact]
public async Task UpdateUser() {
    //Arrange
    var expectedId = 1;
    var expectedName = "John Doe";
    var expectedUser = new User(expectedId, expectedName);

    var repository = new Mock<IUserRepository>();
    repository.Setup(r => r.Get(expectedId)).ReturnsAsync(expectedUser);        

    var userService = new UserService(repository.Object, SingletonAutoMapper.Mapper);
    var userInput = new UserInput { Name = "John Doe" };

    //Act
    await userService.Update(expectedId, userInput);

    //Assert
    repository.Verify(_ => _.Update(expectedUser), Times.Once());
}
```

Comment: You removed `repository.Setup(r => r.Update(It.IsAny<User>()));`. Can you explain why?

Comment: Since it does nothing then there is no need to set it up. It does nothing